# Is there a way to pass the DbSet<T> into the page?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

I have the window with the page. The page displays a data from the my database. Also, on the window the buttons are placed, whose contents is according to the tables names of the database. These buttons switchs the page's content.

For example, this is the `btnUsers` button's click event, which displays the "Users" table:

```
void btnUsers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.FrameMain.Navigate(new pageTable(Context.ctx.Users, ...));
}
```

The `pageTable` is the my "generic" page, that receives the `Users` class. Here is its constructor, which doesn't works:

```
public pageTable(dynamic table, ...) {
    InitializeComponent();

    TableTemplate<dynamic>.Init(table, ...);
}
```

Here is the my generic class, that operates on the `DbSet<T>`:

```
static class TableTemplate<T> {
    internal static void Init(T table) {
        foreach (string f in Foo(table, ...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The `Foo` method just extracts the columns from the `DbSet<T>` table:

```
internal static string Foo<T>(T item, ...) {
    ...
}
```

The point is, that the application terminates when I try to get the data from the table, at the button's event, used this generic approach.

I noticed, that at the `Foo` method, during the debug, the `T` type is differs, depending on the way, with which I pass the `DbSet<T>`:

- if I explicitly initialize a new class instance (for the test):

  ```
  static class TableTemplate<T> {
      internal static void Init(T table) {
          foreach (string f in Foo(new Users(), ...) {
              ...
          }
      }
  }
  ```

  , then the `T` type is `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Users_E006B3...`, and the `Foo` method is works;
- without the explicitly initialization the `T` type is `` System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[Namespace.Users] ``, and the `Foo` method isn't works.

Is there a possibility to pass the generic entity class into the page? I don't know if XAML has a generic classes support, to use the generic `pageTable<T>` page. It could be a solution, but I suppose there is a more neat way to pass the entity.

Comment: It seems like you are making this way more complicated for yourself than necessary. Why do you need this setup of generic methods? What are you actually trying to achieve here? This seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Xerillio, edited the question. Interesting article. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, and it doesn't use the generic page.

Well, when I tried to print the `table` content, I discovered, that pass a structured query into the `TableTemplate.Init()`. I remember, that never used the `dbContext.TableClass` as a function argument before, always converting the `TableClass` into the list.

I confess, I don't understand the EntityFramework and didn't expect such a result. Generally, I used the `object` type and already forgot why used the `dynamic` type...

I decided to pass the `DbSet<T>`, converted to the list (and this, as I understand it, are the different thigns) into the page's constructor, instead of the `DbSet<T>`. But, because I doesn't use the general page, I converted the items of this list into the `object`:

```
void btnUsers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.FrameMain.Navigate(new pageTable(Context.ctx.Users.ToList<object>()));
}
```

Now, the `pageTable` page's constructor is next:

```
public pageTable(List<object> table) {
    InitializeComponent();

    TableTemplate<object>.Init(table, ...);
}
```

And, the `Init` method of the `TableTemplate` class is next:

```
internal static void Init(List<T> tableList) {
    if (tableList.Count > 0) {
        foreach (string f in Foo(tableList[0], ...) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't figured out how to display only the table's columns names, if `tableList` is empty. Thus, in this case, for now the page displays the empty `DataGrid` without the columns names. Nevertheless, I am glad, that could do I wanted.

At last, I will say, that indirectly agree with [Xerillio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3034273/xerillio).